# icc is not performing loop invariant code motion

Tags: c++, c, for-loop, compiler-optimization, icc

Can someone explain the reson why icc is not doing loop invariant code motion (of moving pointer assignment of a) in code 1 below. I see a 40% improvement in performance when the a pointer assignment is moved out of the t6 loop as done in code 2. I tried marking pointer 'a' as a const and restrict, to let compiler know that pointer 'a' will not be changed inside t6 loop. I am compiling code with -ansi-alias option in icc.

//code 1

```
          for (t4=256*t1; t4<=256*t1+254; t4++) {
            lbv=256*t2;
            ubv=256*t2+255;
            for (t6=lbv; t6<=ubv; t6++) { 
                double *restrict const a = a_trans[lbv /256]; //loop invariant code
                a[t6-lbv]=a[t6-lbv]/a[t6-lbv];
            }
          }
```

//code 2

```
       for (t4=256*t1; t4<=256*t1+254; t4++) {
            lbv=256*t2;
            ubv=256*t2+255;
            double *restrict const a = a_trans[lbv /256];
            for (t6=lbv; t6<=ubv; t6++) {
                a[t6-lbv]=a[t6-lbv]/a[t6-lbv];
            }
       }
```

This code is generated by a source to source translator. It is very tedious to manually 
apply this transformation for lots of loops. Is there a way to enable icc to do this transformation automatically?

Answer (score 1):

It seems both `a_trans` and `lbv` are defined in a outer scope and are not constants. You cannot expect that icc is smart enough to understand `a` will not change. For large scope variables like `a_trans` and `lbv`, compiler will assign them in RAM. It's possible that they are changed during the loop. In fact if they are defined as local variables (assigned in registers), the compiler may be able to optimize it.

```
      for (t4=256*t1; t4<=256*t1+254; t4++) {
        lbv=256*t2;
        ubv=256*t2+255;
        const int local_lbv=lbv;
        const double** local_a_trans=a_trans;
        for (t6=lbv; t6<=ubv; t6++) { 
            double *restrict const a = local_a_trans[local_lbv /256];
            a[t6-lbv]=a[t6-lbv]/a[t6-lbv];
        }
      }
```

Generally compilers are designed to compile and optimize code written by human, but not by source code translator.

On the other hand you could try to do more aggressive code optimization with `-O3` and `-ipo`

### EDIT

After trying to localize the variables, there's still no performance improvement. I think we can make a conclusion that code generator won't generate code with high enough performance. A manually rewriting is recommended after the automatic generation.

Comment: If you can do that, why not just move that line out of the loop?

Comment: Problem exists even after you make 'lbv' as a local variable and mark 'a_trans' as const/restrict with in the function. I have used '-03' and '-ipo' options in icc.  Is there any other keyword that I can use to let icc know that 'a_trans' will not be changed with loop?

Comment: As I mentioned earlier this code is generated by source to source translator, I can easily change the text in the innermost for loop body, but cannot add text in between for loops. 'lbv' is already local in generated code.

Comment: Try to make them both local and const. You may expect to much if you counts on a source code translator.

Comment: I tried making a_trans also local, by  adding 'double** local_a_trans=a_trans;' before the t4 loop itself, still not getting performance

Comment: better before t6 loop to make it local enough, and use `const double**`